# Is there a way to modify property values by getters and setters using realm database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Using realm database on node, I need to amend/trim a property value such as `firstName` when Realm constructs a person.

However, a [quote](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest#models) on Realm docs draws my attention:

> At this point, support for defining models via classes is limited. It
>   works in React Native but not in Node.

I am not sure if my problem is the case in current version of realm `v2.8.0`.

```
class Person {
  set firstName(firstName) {
    this._firstName = firstName.trim();
  }
}

Person.schema = {
  name: 'Person',
  properties: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string'
  }
};

// ---

realm.write(() => {
  const john = realm.create('Person', {
    firstName: ' John  ', // <-- need to be trimmed on model
    lastName: 'Smith'
  });
});
```

**Is there a way to modify property values by getters/setters on model? or Is there any other alternative?**

Another consideration is that Realm constructs objects from model and this also my result in an error if I modify them using setters or even on constructor.

```
constructor() {
  this.firstName = this.firstName.trim();
}
```

> Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```js
realm.write(() => {
  const firstName = '  John    ';
  const john = realm.create('Person', {
    firstName: firstName.trim(), // <-- need to be trimmed
    lastName: 'Smith'
  });
});
```

Before assigning the value to `firstName` in `create` method, store that into another variable and trim it when assigning?

Comment: Of course it is possible to do so. However, I am looking a way to amend on model class. In addition, the assumption is that property values come from frontend side as a dictionary.

Comment: @hallaji: you have defined `firstName` to be a `string` in `Person.schema`. May I know what **amend on model class** exactly means?

Comment: I mean like trimming a first name or another example like removing special chars from a first name within a setter on model.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, opening a Realm wrapped with custom logic such as specific configuration and migrated schemas:

```
import Realm from './realm';

let persister = null;

class Person {

  constructor() {
    persister = Realm.open();
  }

  get firstName() {
    return this._firstName;
  }

  set firstName(firstName) {
    this._firstName = firstName.trim();
  }

  async save() {
    try {
      const realm = await persister;
      this.id = uuidv4();
      this.createdAt = Date();
      realm.write(() => {
        realm.create(this.constructor.name, this);
      });

      return this;
    } catch (e) {
      this.handleError(e);
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

The setters/getters take care of the property values such as trimming, etc and an asynchronous method saves the person object on the Realm database as below:

```
const person = new Person();
person.firstName = '      John   ';
person.lastName = 'Smith';

person.save().then((p) => {
  console.log(p.firstName); // persisted trimmed firstName
});

// OR within async function:
let p = await person.save();
console.log(p.firstName); // persisted trimmed firstName
```